# How can I use variable value as a parameter to grepl in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, pattern-matching, grepl

Below is my code:

```
ABData <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     id = c("Non valid cases with no consent for follow-up (a)", "Oxford", "Berlin",
                           "Hamburg", "Oslo"),
                     pass = c("CASE ARCHIVED - ACTELION LEGACY CASE :ST_NVC_CATEGORY_NAME Non valid cases with no consent for follow-up (a)","No London","asdBerlin","No Match","OsLondonlohama"))

b <- 'id'
c <- 'pass'

match<- ABData %>% rowwise() %>% filter(grepl(id,pass, fixed = TRUE))

mismatch<- ABData %>% rowwise() %>% filter(!grepl(id, pass))
```

I want to use variable b and c as a parameter in `grepl` but at that time I didn't get the correct result and when I use actual column name of dataframe I get the correct result.

Help!!

Comment: Why would you want to pass a variable if its not a function? If it was a function it would be easy. You could have used the quasi quotations. But now, I am not quite sure. You could try `ABData %>% rowwise() %>%
  filter(grepl(get(b),get(c), fixed = TRUE))` but this is not the good idea to go about it. Check the [programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) learn more about NSE.

Comment: get() is working fine. I am having dynamic column name in various data frames so i thought i will go with this approach ..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sym` with `!!` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(rlang)

ABData %>% rowwise %>% filter(grepl(!!sym(b),!!sym(c), fixed = TRUE))
```

However, instead of using `grepl` you can use `str_detect` which is vectorised so you don't need `rowwise` :

```
ABData %>% filter(str_detect(!!sym(c), fixed(!!sym(b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` with `.data`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
ABData %>%
       filter(map2_lgl(.data[[c]], .data[[b]], ~ grepl(.y, .x, fixed = TRUE )))
```